# How to get branch hash using git command

Tags: git

I have JenkinsFile where I'm trying to get the hash for my current branch. I saw this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110478/how-to-find-the-hash-of-branch-in-git

but when I tried to run `def BranchHash = sh "git rev-parse ${BRANCH-NAME}` I got: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`

I'm looking for the branch hash, and not the last commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git show -s --format="%H" <HEAD or Branch Name>
```

`-s` supressess the diff output

`--format="%H"` specifies that only the hash should be shown.

See `man git-show` for more details.